# ClickHouse - запрос к таблице выводит ошибку, что не хватает полей, которых нет в самой таблице

Tags: clickhouse

Пишу метод, в котором два запроса к БД. Первый запрос с первой таблице отрабатывает нормально, выводит нужный результат. Второй запрос к уже другой таблице падает с ошибкой, что не хватает столбцов, при том, что этих столбцов в обрабатываемой таблице нет. Host [myHost] returned error: Code: 47, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Missing columns:(перечисление столбцов из другой таблицы).

```
       public function myMethod($par1, $par2)
    {
// first query
        $dataOffer = $this->getBuilder()
            ->table('table1')
            ->select('countries')
            ->where('link', $par2)
            ->get();
        $result1 = Arr::first($dataOffer->rows)['countries'];

// second query
        $dataUser = $this->getBuilder()
            ->table('table2')
            ->select('country_code')
            ->where('start_ip', '<=', $par1)
            ->where('end_ip', '>=', $par1)
            ->get();
        $result2 = Arr::first($dataUser->rows)['country_code'];
    }
```

Comment: Вопрос ещё не решил, но такая ошибка вышла потому, что в $this->getBuilder() оставалась часть предыдущего запроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно, чтобы getBuilder() каждый раз создавал новый объект:

```
return new Builder($this->client)
```

Comment: Для полноты картины, покажите, пожалуйста, в вопросе `getBuilder()` каким он был, а тут каким его сделали :)

Comment: @gil9red return new Builder($this->client)